# If $AB = BA$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$, then $A$ and $B$ have these properties

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There is a base such $A$ and $B$ are both upper triangular on these base, and if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, then $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable simultaneously.

For the first I have no idea. To the second one I am trying to show something like: Iv $v$ is an eigenvector for $A$ then $Bv$ is an eigenvector for $A$.

To the second I proceeded as:

$$v \in \ker (A - \lambda * Id)$$ for same $\lambda \neq 0$, then

$$Bv = B\frac{1}{\lambda}Av = \frac{1}{\lambda}BAv = \frac{1}{\lambda}ABv$$

Then

$$A(Bv) = \lambda Bv$$ and then $Bv$ is an eigenvector for $A$ also with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

But I am stuck here. I mean, I don't know what to do with this.

I do appreciate any hint or answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054886/prove-two-commutative-linear-transformations-on-a-vector-space-over-an-algebraic

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/simultaneously-diagonalizable-proof

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=simultaneous+diagonalizable

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=simultaneous+triangularizable

Comment: Please, do some research before posting questions